# Typescript tsc.exe does nothing on build and hangs my solution build

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm just getting into typescript and I'm running into an annoying issue that is slowing me down.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and I've installed the Update 2 to get the typescript support.  I've successfully added a typescript project and have multiple typescript files that I have configured to compile to a single javascript output.  I also have compile on save turned on which appears to be working fine.

The problem occurs when I try to build/run the application.  Most of the time, the build just sits there indefinitely (I've waited up to 10 min), until I cancel it.  I can see that the tsc.exe process is spawned when I start the build, but it has 0 cpu activity.  The weird thing is, this doesn't happen every single time.  1 out of ever 5 or 6 attempts, tsc.exe fires up and goes to work immediately and the build completes fine in about 10 seconds or so.

Is there anything I need to configure to get tsc.exe to execute consistently.  I believe I have typescript version 1.0 installed which is what VS 2013 Update 2 installed.

Comment: You might want to explore other options : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts

Comment: What else do you have installed on the machine? Do other JavaScript-based apps function OK? Have you tried doing a repair install? You might try using the node package for tsc instead.